# start program at bootup

Tags: autostart

I need to make a program run at start up as root. The program is.

```
/usr/bin/svxlink
```

I'm running Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS

I just cant get it to work. Can someone walk me thru the steps to do this.
Thank you for any help.

I have been reading all night but just can't get it to work. Not just asking without trying to do it myself.

I put this into /etc/init.d

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:        svxlink
# Required-Start:  $network $local_fs $syslog $ntp
# Required-Stop:   
# Default-Start:   2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:    0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start SvxLink Server daemon
### END INIT INFO

# Use the following command to activate the start script
#   update-rc.d svxlink start 30 2 3 4 5 . stop 70 0 1 6 .

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

PNAME=svxlink
NAME="SvxLink Server"
DAEMON=/usr/bin/$PNAME

test -x $DAEMON || exit 5

if [ -r /etc/default/$PNAME ]; then
. /etc/default/$PNAME
fi

POPTS="--daemon ${RUNASUSER:+--runasuser=$RUNASUSER} ${PIDFILE:+--pidfile=$PIDFILE} ${LOGFILE:+--logfile=$LOGFILE} ${CFGFILE:+--config=$CFGFILE}"

create_logfile()
{
touch $LOGFILE
if [ -n "$RUNASUSER" ]; then
    chown $RUNASUSER.$RUNASUSER $LOGFILE
fi
}

case $1 in
start)
    log_daemon_msg "Starting $NAME: $PNAME"
    create_logfile
    export $ENV
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --startas $DAEMON -- $POPTS
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
stop)
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping $NAME: $PNAME"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE
    log_end_msg $?
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    ;;
restart|force-reload)
    $0 stop && sleep 2 && $0 start
    ;;
try-restart)
    if $0 status >/dev/null; then
        $0 restart
    else
        exit 0
    fi
    ;;
reload)
    exit 3
    ;;
status)
    pidofproc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON >/dev/null
    status=$?
    if [ $status -eq 0 ]; then
        log_success_msg "$NAME is running."
    else
        log_failure_msg "$NAME is not running."
    fi
    exit $status
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|try-restart|force-reload|status}"
    exit 2
    ;;
esac
```

And i get.

Executing /etc/init.d/svxlink start ..

```
* Starting SvxLink Server: svxlink
touch: missing file operand
Try 'touch --help' for more information.
export HOME='/root'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=''
export PATH='/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin'
export PERLLIB='/usr/share/webmin'
export PWD='/usr/share/webmin/init/'
export REMOTE_ADDR='192.168.4.25'
export REMOTE_ADDR_PROTOCOL='4'
export SERVER_REALROOT='/usr/share/webmin'
start-stop-daemon: --start needs --exec or --startas
Try 'start-stop-daemon --help' for more information.
   ...fail!
```

Comment: Just to be clear: this is the first run of the script and you haven't done an update-rd.d yet, right?  Have you tried running the script in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

Running A Program At Start UP A Beginner's Guide
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=314455

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1303278)